# error while loading the webview

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-webview

I am using a webview in my fragment.

```
private void LoadWebView()
{
    privacy_Webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    privacy_Webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    privacy_Webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
```

I am getting the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.webkit.WebSettings android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()' on a null object reference
```

The error is occurred at the line :-
 privacy_Webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

On a button click from one fragment this fragment gets load in which it has the web view.

I cant figure out the issue.

Comment: Did you gave internet permission in manifest file?

Comment: yes i already give that

Comment: is your webview `wv_privacy` present in `fragment_forgot_password` layout?

Comment: @SripadRajm yes it is present

Comment: I dont think so. Could you please check? You're trying to access a view which is not present in your layout. So it throws a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @ SripadRaj  thanks bro you were right really thanku

Comment: Now the error is removed but the screen still appears white  @SripadRaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your `fragment_forgot_password` doesn't contain `wv_privacy`, so `rootView.findViewById(R.id.wv_privacy)` returns `null`.

Comment: Now the error is removed but the screen still appears white @Artyom